# When Time Series data is offset and incomplete

Tags: r

A new client at work has a fiscal calendar that starts in March and ends in February of the following year:

```
fiscalMonthLabels <- c("March", "April", "May", "June", 
  "July", "August", "September", "October", 
  "November", "December", "January", "February")
```

But, because they are new, we only have a few months' worth of data:

```
library(lubridate)
rawDate <- c("2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01")
actualMonth <- month(rawDate)
newMonth <- rep(0, length(actualMonth))
for (i in 1:length(actualMonth)) {
  if (actualMonth[i] == 1) {newMonth[i] <- 11} 
  else if (actualMonth[i] == 2) {newMonth[i] <- 12} 
  else {newMonth[i] <- actualMonth[i] - 2}
}
revenue <- c(123, 456, 789)

df <- data.frame(rawDate, actualMonth, newMonth, revenue)
df
     rawDate actualMonth newMonth revenue
1 2018-09-01           9        7     123
2 2018-10-01          10        8     456
3 2018-11-01          11        9     789
```

So when I try to create a new factor with the fiscal month, this is the error I get:

```
fiscalMonth <- factor(newMonth, labels = fiscalMonthLabels)

Error in factor(newMonth, labels = fiscalMonthLabels) : 
    invalid 'labels'; length 12 should be 1 or 3
```

It seems like the `factor` command is looking for `actualMonth` to contain all twelve possible values in it. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: I made an edit, just so it's clear that the new months will be numbered appropriately to reflect the calendar shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to assign the `levels` too:

```
fiscalMonth <- factor(actualMonth, levels = 1:12, labels = fiscalMonthLabels)
fiscalMonth
[1] November December January 
Levels: March April May June July August September October November December January February
```

Alternatively, since you're using `lubridate::month`, you could just pass the label argument to month, which will return an ordered factor:

```
fiscalMonth <- month(actualMonth, label = TRUE)
[1] Sep Oct Nov
Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec
```